# PowerShell Regex: Capturing strings between two strings that is on multiple lines

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-group, regex-greedy, capturing-group

I may have something like this:

```
FIRST|[some text here] (newline)
[insert text here] (newline)
SECOND|A (newline)

FIRST|[some text here] (newline)
[insert text here] (newline)
SECOND|B (newline)

FIRST|[some text here] (newline)
[insert text here] (newline)
SECOND|A (newline)

FIRST|[some text here] (newline)
[insert text here] (newline)
SECOND|B (newline)

FIRST|[some text here] (newline)
[insert text here] (newline)
SECOND|A (newline)
```

I only want to capture everything from `FIRST` to `SECOND|B` and exclude anything from `FIRST` to `SECOND|A`.
The order in this post is just an example and may be different with the files I am working with. The text in brackets could be words, digits, special characters, etc. (newline) is just telling you that it is on a different line.
I have tried https://regex101.com/r/CwzCyz/2 (`FIRST[\s\S]+SECOND\|B`) but that gives me from the first FIRST to the last SECOND|B
This works in regex101.com but not in my PowerShell ISE application, which I am guessing is because I have the flavor set to PCRE(PHP).

Comment: Use `-Raw` when getting file content and then use `(?s)FIRST.*?SECOND\|B`

Comment: That doesn't quite work, because `SECOND|A` will still be returned as part of the match until `SECOND|B` is encountered.

Comment: Are `A` and `B` really the letters A & B or do they represent something else. Could we find `SECOND|C` or `SECOND|Z` or something else.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FIRST\|(?:(?!SECOND\|[^B])[\S\s])*?SECOND\|B`

will not match the FIRST| associated with the SECOND|A (or any non-B)

https://regex101.com/r/e0CG9B/1

Expanded

```
 FIRST \| 
 (?:
      (?! SECOND \| [^B] )
      [\S\s] 
 )*?
 SECOND \| B
```

---

If there is a need for the absolute inner FIRST / SECOND that has to be done a different way :

`FIRST\|(?:(?!(?:FIRST|SECOND)\|)[\S\s])*SECOND\|B`

https://regex101.com/r/qoT8U1/1

Answer (score 1):

If `FIRST` is at the start of the line and `SECOND|A` or `SECOND|B` is at the start of the line you could match all following lines that do not start with `SECOND\|[AB]`

```
^FIRST.*(?:\r?\n(?!SECOND\|[AB]\b).*)\r?\nSECOND\|B\b.*
```

In parts

- `^FIRST.*` Start of the line
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n(?!SECOND\|[AB]\b)` Match a newline, assert not starting with the `SECOND` part
  - `.*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `SECOND\|B\b.*` Match the line that starts with SECOND|B

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SQYPj5/1)